# Stop chromium animation when de-iconifying

Tags: chrome, window-manager

I just upgraded to chromium 58.  Suddenly de-iconifying chromium, which used to have imperceptible latency, runs through an annoying animation that lasts several hundred milliseconds.

To see this, just use a window manager with icons (I use fvwm2), iconify a chromium window, and then de-iconify it.  It takes forever compared to every other application (xterm, emacs, firefox) that de-iconifies seemingly instantaneously.

My question: Is there some setting I can use to disable this annoying animation?

Comment: I don't see this but then I'm using Chrome, not Chromium. Does anything in `chrome://flags/` look plausible? I have smooth scrolling turned off, the rest as default.

Comment: @Gilles No, I already looked through the flags.  To be more precise, I'm using chromium 58.0.3029.81.  What version are you on?